# Convert list of objects to enum entries c#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

How does one pass a list of Class objects to an enum?

Currently I have a class structure that is pulling data from an XML file. Here is what they look like:

```
[XmlRoot("ManufacturerContainer")]
public class ManufacturerContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Manufacturers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Manufacturer")]
    public List<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Model")]
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }    
}

public class Model
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

What I'm trying to do is create 2 enum dropdown boxes, the Model dropdown being dependent on the Manufacturer. You would select the Manufacturer and the Models will update. How do you go about dynamically changing an enum?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure enums are the right solution to your problem, since you can't update them at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can't / shouldn't try to change an `enum` at runtime. To say it in simple words an `enum` is kind of comparable to a `constant` Dictionary which you can not alter at runtime.

Even if one could, any code (e.g. switch-case, or any if-else depending on that enum might fail).

---

There is no simple fast solution. For what you want to do you would have to get deep into Unity Editor scripting and create your custom [Popup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) using a `string[]` as options (e.g. the names here) and

First I would add some getter methods to you classes (all assuming the `Name`s in your example are unique and none of the manufacturers or models within one manufacturer have the same name):

```c#
[XmlRoot("ManufacturerContainer")]
public class ManufacturerContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Manufacturers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Manufacturer")]
    public List<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

    // Get all available Manufacturers' names
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAvailableManufacturers()
    {
        // use Linq to get a list of only the names
        return Manufacturers.Select(manufacturer => manufacturer.Name);
    }

    // Get a specific Manufacturer by name
    public Manufacturer GetManufacturerByName(string name)
    {
        // a little sanaty check
        if (GetAvailableManufacturers().Contains(name))
        {
            // again use Linq to return the Manufacturer by name
            // (provided that they are unique of course)
            return Manufacturers.Find(manufacturer => string.Equals(name, manufacturer.Name));
        }

        Debug.LogWarningFormat("No Manufacturer with name {0} found!", name);
        return null;
    }

    // and finally get a specific Model by manufacturer and model name
    public Model GetModelByName(string manufacturerId, string modelId)
    {
        // first get the according manufacturer
        var manufacturer = GetManufacturerByName(manufacturerId);

        if (manufacturer != null)
        {
            // get the model by name (see method below)
            return manufacturer.GetModelByName(modelId);
        }

        Debug.LogWarningFormat("Couldn't get Manufacturer with id {0}", manufacturerId);
        return null;

        // then the according model
    }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")] public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Model")] public List<Model> Models { get; set; }

    // Get all available Models' names
    public List<string> GetAvailableModels()
    {
        return Models.Select(model => model.Name).ToList();
    }

    // The same as for getting a Manufacturer by name
    public Model GetModelByName(string name)
    {
        // a little sanaty check
        if (GetAvailableModels().Contains(name))
        {
            // again use Linq to return the Model by name
            // (provided that they are unique of course)
            return Models.Find(model => string.Equals(name, model.Name));
        }

        Debug.LogWarningFormat("No Manufacturer with name {0} found!", name);
        return null;
    }
}

public class Model
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")] public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So now you are able to

- Get all available options for manufacturers and their models
- Later find a specific manufacturer/model by Id (e.g. in case you need further info on them etc)

So the next step is writing a [CustomEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) or a [CustomPropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) for your class depending on what you need.

I'll give you a very simplified idea of how a PropertyDrawer could look like. Unfortunately Editor scripting always grows huge and there are a lot of things you have to do manually:

```c#
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ModelSelection))]
public class ModelSelectionDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    // Lets just say we want the property to have a height of 3 lines
    // one for the label, and one for each dropdown
    // It makes it easier for now to place the dropdowns
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 3;
    }

    // Kind of like the Inspectors update method
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that
        // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        // Draw label
        EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label);
        // go to next line
        position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // Don't make child fields be indented
        var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;


        // first of all link the according variables
        var _manufacturerId = property.FindPropertyRelative("ManufacturerId");
        var _modelId = property.FindPropertyRelative("ModelId");

        // You somehow need access to the reference of ManufacturerContainer
        // I will assume here you now how to make it accessable all over your scene 
        // and pretend it is already stored in this variable

        // I just create one right here in order to have something to show already
        var container = new ManufacturerContainer
        {
            Manufacturers = new List<Manufacturer>
            {
                new Manufacturer
                {
                    Name = "Man_1",
                    Models = new List<Model>
                    {
                        new Model
                        {
                            Name = "Model_A"
                        },
                        new Model
                        {
                            Name = "Model_B"
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Manufacturer
                {
                    Name = "Man_2",
                    Models = new List<Model>
                    {
                         new Model
                         {
                             Name = "Model_C"
                         },
                         new Model
                         {
                             Name = "Model_D"
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Now you would get the available manufacturers
        var availableManufacturers = container.GetAvailableManufacturers().ToArray();

        // Make the dropdown field for manufacturer
        // Get the position for this field
        var field1_rect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);
        // add a label
        field1_rect = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(field1_rect, new GUIContent("Manufacturer"));
        position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // get index of currently selected manufacturer
        var currentManIndex = availableManufacturers.ToList().IndexOf(_manufacturerId.stringValue);
        // clamp to minimum 0 (it returns -1 if the string is incorrect/not found in the list)
        currentManIndex = Mathf.Max(currentManIndex, 0);

        // problem it returns an int -> index
        // => if you add or delete an item later in middle the XML it breaks
        // you would have to fix this on your own
        var newManIndex = EditorGUI.Popup(field1_rect, currentManIndex, availableManufacturers.ToArray());

        // now we have the new index but we have to write back the selected object to the target class
        _manufacturerId.stringValue = availableManufacturers[newManIndex];



        // Now that you have a manufacturer selected you can get and select the model
        var availableModels = container.GetManufacturerByName(_manufacturerId.stringValue).GetAvailableModels().ToArray();

        // Make the dropdown field for manufacturer
        // Get the position for this field
        var field2_rect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);
        // add a label
        field2_rect = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(field2_rect, new GUIContent("Model"));
        position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // get index of currently selected manufacturer
        var currentModIndex = availableModels.ToList().IndexOf(_modelId.stringValue);
        // also clamp this to minimum 0
        currentModIndex = Mathf.Max(currentModIndex, 0);


        // problem it returns an int -> index
        // => if you add or delete an item later in middle the XML it breaks
        // you would have to fix this on your own
        var newModIndex = EditorGUI.Popup(field2_rect, currentModIndex, availableModels.ToArray());

        // now we have the new index but we have to write back the selected object to the target class
        _modelId.stringValue = availableModels[newModIndex];

        // Set indent back to what it was
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

As said this is just an example and there are surely a lot of more checks and things that should be added. But you would use this property later in any class like

```c#
public class Blarf : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ModelSelection selection;
}
```

and it would look like this in the editor:

[image]

The rest depends on what is your goal to do after one selects those two values. You could e.g. simply want to get the according `Model` using

```c#
// reference to your container
container.GetModelByName(selection.ManufacturerId, selection.ModelId);
```